# Difference between cerebroside and globoside

Tags: biochemistry, terminology, lipids

I have a general idea about their difference that cerebrosides have a single sugar while globosides have more than one sugars.

[image]

This is the structure of a ceramide (syphingosine and a fatty acid linked through amide linkage).

It's not clear to me that do cerebrosides have a single monosaccharide on only one -OH group of the syphingosine, two monosaccharides on each of the two -OH groups, or one oligosaccharide on only one -OH group.

Likewise I am not sure if globosides have a single oligosaccharide on only one - OH group of syphingosine, or two monosaccharides on each of the two -OH groups, or two oligosaccharides on each of the two -OH group.

If you have any knowledge about this, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is Encyclopedia about cerebroside 
[image]
https://www.guidechem.com/dictionary_keys_cerebroside-p1.html
and this is about globoside
[image]
https://www.guidechem.com/dictionary_keys_globoside-p1.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globoside
I hope this can help you.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.